# cp SOMEFILE .. copies to a different directory after cd'ing via a symbolic link

Tags: shell, symlink, cp, cd-command

Consider the following setup:

```
~/Desktop/Public/subdir
~/Desktop/subdir --> ~/Desktop/Public/subdir (symbolic link)
```

Now I do:

```
cd ~/Desktop/subdir
```

Which leads me into the linked directory.

If I now issue the command:

```
cd ..
```

I will be moved back into the `Desktop` directory. This means the cd command is context sensitive - it remembers that I entered `subdir` via the symbolic link.

However, issuing the command

```
cp testfile ..
```

will copy `testfile` into `Desktop/Public`.

I prefer the behavior of `cd` over the (often unpredictable) behavior of `cp`. In any case, I wonder what is the reason for this difference in behavior? Just a legacy thing or is there a good reason?

Comment: Btw., behaviour and behavior are both correct spellings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that `cd` is aware that you have entered the directory via a `symlink` is because it is built-in to the shell. The `cp` command is an external binary and is only passed data via command line arguments and environment variables. Environment variables do not contain data on *how* you entered the current directory.

If you are using `bash`, you can make `cd` function the same as `cp` if you want things to be consistent. `set -P` will accomplish this. From the manpage:

```
          -P      If  set,  the shell does not follow symbolic links when executing commands such as cd that change the current working directory.  It uses the physical directory structure instead.  By default, bash follows the
                  logical chain of directories when performing commands which change the current directory.
```

Comment: Actually, the PWD environment variable _does_ contain data on how you entered the current directory.  `cp` just doesn't use it like Bash does.

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice if it did? I understand that there are legacy issues, but I think it would be much more user friendly if cp did consider the fact that I entered via a symbolic link.

Comment: @Konstantin Only shells set `PWD`. So if a shell starts program1 which starts program2, then program2 has no idea whether `$PWD` is still up-to-date. `cp` has no way to know that you entered through a symbolic link, this tracking is internal to the shell.

Answer (score 2):

When `cd` works as described it can only be a trick of `cd` or your shell. `..` is an entry to the parent directory. In your case the parent of `subdir` can only be `Public` and not `Desktop`. Thus `cp` does the right think and you will get the same behavior with redirects (like `>`).

The cd example only uses some "user-friendly" trick to behave like it does. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456784/behavior-of-cd-bash-on-symbolic-links

If you really need the functionality you have to use something like

```
cp testfile "${PWD##*/}"
```

(copy to the parent directory of the current directory, according to shell tracking). In zsh, you can simplify this to `cp testfile $PWD:h`

Answer (score 1):

It's rather the opposite: `cp` behaves like any other application, it interprets `..` as the parent directory of the current directory. That's because the kernel interprets `..` as the parent directory of the current directory.

When you run `cd` through a symbolic link, the path that you pass to `cd` does not make the parent directory of the destination directory apparent. When you run `cd ~/Desktop/subdir`, the destination is not `/home/konstantin/Desktop/subdir` — that's a symbolic link. The destination directory is `/home/konstantin/Desktop/Public/subdir`. (Or, to be pedantic: the destination directory is a subdirectory called `subdir` of a subdirectory called `Public` of … of a subdirectory called `home` of the root directory.) `/home/konstantin/Desktop/subdir/..` is not `/home/konstantin/Desktop`: the property that the parent directory of `/…stuff…/subdir` is `/…stuff…` only holds in the absence of subdirectories.

Because it's often convenient to think of symbolic links to directories as if they were directories, shells perform symbolic link tracking. When you run `cd`, the shell remembers which path (possibly using symbolic links) you've used to reach the destination. And when you use `..` in an argument to `cd` (or similar shell builtins such as `pushd`), the shell performs a textual interpretation of `..` rather than interpreting it as the current directory: `cd /some/stuff/../more` is transformed to `cd /some/more`. That way, `cd` behaves as if the symbolic links were actually directories.

Textual interpretation of `..` is known as logical directory tracking, and filesystem interpretation of `..` is known as physical directory tracking.
If you want to use physical directory tracking (i.e. to turn off textual interpretation of `..`), pass the `-P` option to `cd`. The `-L` option forces logical tracking on, in case it's been disabled. Logical tracking is off by default; you can turn it off with `set -P` in bash or with `setopt chase_links` in zsh.

The command `pwd` displays the current directory as tracked by the shell. Like `cd`, you can pass the option `-L` or `-P` to force logical or physical tracking.

All this is happening inside the shell. External applications such as `cp` have no way to know what tracking the shell is doing internally. So if you want to use logical directory tracking in an argument to a command, you need to convert that first to a path that doesn't depend on logical tracking.

The shell variable `PWD` keeps track of the current directory (`$PWD` contains the same string that `pwd` prints). If you want to strip off the last textual component of the tracked path to the current directory, instead of appending `/..` which only works with logical tracking, you can use a textual method.

```
cp testfile "${PWD##*/}"
```

or in zsh:

```
cp testfile $PWD:h
```

If you want to type `..` and not have to think about expressing the directory differently, run `cd` to the desired target directory, and then use the path to the destination in the argument of the command.

```
cp testfile "$(cd .. && pwd)"
```